# Two Domain Names, Single Hosting, htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have two domains; sitea.com and siteb.com.
Each domain points to the same hosting account.
The content served is identical.
Basically, I have two domain names that serve the same identical content (links, pages, etc).

What I want is to keep the same url depending on how the user entered the site.  Meaning, if they arrived using sitea.com in the address bar... then all links should show "sitea" as the root domain, and all visited pages will show "sitea.com/help" for example.

If the user arrived via "siteb.com", then all links and visited pages should show "siteb.com" as the root.

What I want to avoid is if the user enters "sitea.com" in the address bar; they get redirected to "siteb.com" (which is what is currently happening).

I accomplished this successfully once before using htaccess rules.  But, alas, I cannot recall the rules.

**EDIT**:
MY two domain names are industrialpolymer.org and wheelhandling.com.  The hosting account I have is tied to the "industrialpolymer.org" domain.

Currently, when a user types "wheelhandling.com" in their address bar; they are redirected to "industrialpolymer.org".  I would like if they type "wheelhandling.com" in the address bar, it keeps that address, and serves the same content.  Their address bar would always show "wheelhandling.com" as the base url.

Also, I need to keep the "industrialpolymer.org" website operational.  So both domains should perform identically, with the only difference being the domain name of how they entered the site.

My current htaccess is just the default WP one:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Could you please do mention your sample URLs eg--> FROM which url TO which url you want to redirect/rewrite for better understanding of question. Also add your .htaccess file in your question too, thank you.

Comment: Doing it now.  Thank you.

Comment: "I accomplished this successfully once before using htaccess rules." - I don't think you did. WordPress stores the hostname and uses this to create absolute URLs to your internal pages. You'll need to manually override this if the same site is going to be accessible from two domains. You can only do this from within WP itself.

Comment: The only way to do this outside of WordPress would be to configure your _server_ (to which the secondary domain points to) as a _reverse proxy_ to your WordPress site at the main domain. However, this will need more that just `.htaccess`, as the proxy will need to manipulate the HTML (and response headers) and convert all references of the main domain to the secondary domain. WordPress itself will then only think it is at the main domain (it will not be aware of the secondary domain). (?)

Comment: There are plugins that promise they can help with that, for example https://wordpress.org/plugins/make-paths-relative/ (never used it, so you’d have to test it yourself, resp. look for other alternatives if this one doesn’t do what you want.)